# "The total value of orders we were forced to cancel as a result of the pandemic was closer to £200k for stock."

Tags: sentence-construction

> The total value of orders we were forced to cancel as a result of the pandemic was closer to £200k for stock.

This sentence seems like simple sentence as because there is no connector. Is "as"  the connector of this sentence? If as is the connector then the first clause of this sentence uses more than one finite verb. How we use more than one finite verb in a clause?

Comment: What is the source of that sentence? Can you edit your question to include that with a link, please?

Comment: I take this sentence from "Guardian "newspaper. Sorry now I can't share this link because I lose it

Comment: You can treat all of "orders we were forced to cancel as a result of the pandemic" as one thing. If you were to say "The total value of the company was closer to £200k of stock" would that make sense to you?

Comment: Quotation marks indicate the verbatim comments of a source, so all the errors are there to behold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traditional grammar recognizes several kinds of connectors.   There are three kinds of pure connectors: coordinating conjunctions, correlative conjunctions, and subordinating conjunctions.   It also recognizes some connecting words that do more than just connect things, such as relative pronouns, relative adjectives, and relative adverbs.

Another thing that traditional grammar recognizes is sentence structure.   A sentence with only one complete clause is called *a simple sentence.*   A sentence with more than one independent clause is called *a compound sentence.*   A sentence with at least one *subordinate* clause is called *a complex sentence*.

A sentence **can** be **both** *compound* and *complex*.   It cannot be both *simple* and *compound*.   It cannot be both *simple* and *complex*.  In other words, a sentence with more than one clause cannot be simple.

> The total value of orders [that] we **were** <sub>1</sub> forced to cancel as a result of the pandemic **was** <sub>2</sub> closer to £200k for stock.

This sentence has two finite verbs.   Each of those verbs has its own subject.   The sentence has two clauses.

In this sentence, the connector is optional.   The word "that" doesn't appear in the original sentence, but the sentence behaves as if it does.   The clause "[that] we were forced to cancel as a result of the pandemic" is a subordinate clause, a relative clause, and a contact clause (when the word "that" isn't written).

Since the sentence has a subordinate clause, it is not *simple.*   It is *complex.*

> We were forced to cancel **orders** as a result of the pandemic.

According to traditional grammar, this is a simple sentence.   It contains exactly one independent clause.   The word "orders" is the direct object of the infinitive "to cancel".   The entire infinitive phrase "to cancel orders" is a modifier of the verb "forced".   The entire prepositional phrase "as a result of the pandemic" is another modifier of "forced".

> of **orders** [that] we were forced to cancel as a result of the pandemic

This is a prepositional phrase that includes a subordinate clause.   The subordinate clause modifies the noun "orders", and that noun (along with its modifier) is the object of the preposition "of".

The word "that" serves two functions in this example.   Within its own clause, it acts as the direct object of the infinitive "to cancel".   Outside of its own clause, it connects the clause to the noun "orders".

The connector is the relative pronoun "that".

The structure works even when the word "that" isn't written, because the infinitive "to cancel" wants to have a direct object.   We can see what is missing.   In effect, the missing object is what attaches the subordinate clause to the word it modifies:

> of orders <sup><s>[that]</s></sup> we were forced to cancel <sub>{ <s>those same orders</s> }</sub> as a result of the pandemic

Don't say that the original sentence *seems to be simple*.   It seems to be ***not** simple*.   It is obvious to you that there is *more than one clause*, and you are correct to see the sentence in that way.   Instead, say *it seems to be missing a connector.*

What you really want to know is *how the two clauses connect*.

How do the two clauses connect?   In your example sentence, the subordinate clause "we were forced to cancel <sub><s>orders</s></sub> as a result of the pandemic" is a contact clause.   It connects directly to the word "orders", making it one part of the complete subject of the matrix clause.